# jQuery toggle (pulsate) one icon over another

Tags: jquery

I try to achive the following:

I'm using the MDI icon set, but it should of course be the same with any other (fa,...). We have a ticket system up and running and we are implementing something like "Suggest a feature" as well.

Now we have the submit button of the form with an Icon right beside:

I found out that jquery has `$( "#toggle" ).toggle( "pulsate" );` as well and it would look awesome.

Let's imagine the "o" is a bulb that's not on and "ö" is the bulb on. 
It would look awesome if the stays with the bulb off until the user clicks on it. and the bulb-on flickers in. Like an old bulb. The delay of the submit itself should of course delay.

default icon is mdi-lightbulb (o) and onclick mdi-lightbulb-on (ö) should flicker over the mdi-lightbulb icon

*Edit: the button is type="button" to test the effect and not permanently reload the site when trying things out.*

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success toggleicon">
    <i class="mdi mdi-lightbulb tochange"></i> 
    Idee absenden
</button>

*************************************************************

<script>

$('.toggleicon').on('click', function(){
  // $('.tochange').removeClass('mdi-lightbulb');
  // $('.tochange').addClass('mdi-lightbulb-on');
  $('.tochange').toggle( "pulsate" );
});

$('form').submit( function(event) {
    var formId = this.id,
        form = this;
    mySpecialFunction(formId);

    event.preventDefault();

    setTimeout( function () { 
        form.submit();
    }, 1000);
}); 

</script>
```

I have the toggle itself but not the pulsate:

```
  $('.toggleicon').on('click', function(){
    $('.toggleicon').find('i').toggleClass('mdi-lightbulb mdi-lightbulb-on');
  });
```

Comment: Explain the issue again, please ?

Comment: one button, default icon is mdi-lightbulb and onclick mdi-lightbulb-on should flicker over the mdi-lightbulb icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`effect`](https://jqueryui.com/effect/) as opposed to `toggle` so it won't hide the target element, and from here you could simply switch between the classes instead of the element's visibility.

```js
$('#lightbulb').click(function() {
  var $bulb = $(this);
  var state = $bulb.data('on');
  var switches = {
    'false': 'mdi-lightbulb-on',
    'true': 'mdi-lightbulb-outline'
  };

  $('.mdi', this).effect('pulsate', {
    complete: function() {
      $bulb.data('on', !state);

      $(this).removeClass(this.className).addClass('mdi ' + switches[state]);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#lightbulb > .mdi-lightbulb-on {
  color: #ef950f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/3.3.92/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">

<button id="lightbulb" data-on="false">
  <span class="mdi mdi-lightbulb-outline"></span>
  <span class="light-state">Light</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success toggleicon">
    <i class="mdi mdi-lightbulb tochange"></i>
    <i class="mdi mdi-lightbulb-on tochange" style="display:none;"></i>         
    Idee absenden
</button>

*************************************************************
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/3.3.92/css/materialdesignicons.css">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success toggleicon">
    <i class="mdi mdi-lightbulb tochange"></i>
    <i class="mdi mdi-lightbulb-on tochange" style="display:none;"></i>   
    Idee absenden
</button>

*************************************************************
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('.toggleicon').on('click', function(){
  //$('.tochange').removeClass('mdi-lightbulb');
   //$('.tochange').addClass('mdi-lightbulb-on');
  $('.tochange').toggle( "pulsate" );
});

$('form').submit( function(event) {
    var formId = this.id,
        form = this;
    mySpecialFunction(formId);

    event.preventDefault();

    setTimeout( function () { 
        form.submit();
    }, 1000);
}); 

</script>
```

```
<script>

$('.toggleicon').on('click', function(){
        //$('.tochange').removeClass('mdi-lightbulb');
   //$('.tochange').addClass('mdi-lightbulb-on');
  $('.tochange').toggle( "pulsate" );
});

$('form').submit( function(event) {
    var formId = this.id,
        form = this;
    mySpecialFunction(formId);

    event.preventDefault();

    setTimeout( function () { 
        form.submit();
    }, 1000);
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Sukhjinder, thanks for your reply. I had this solution as well, but it's not really doing the effect I hoped for. I'm looking for a pulsate effect on the icons themself. something like here shown with [toggle pulsate](https://api.jqueryui.com/pulsate-effect/)